# Ruby - use data of a response as variable

Tags: ruby, api

I'm making a call by this code

```
require 'riot_api'

# Create Instace of the API
ra = RiotApi::API.new :api_key => 'MY_API', :region => 'na', :debug => true

# Search by Summoner name
summoner_details = ra.summoner.name('GoncyRlz')
```

And I got this response

```
#<Hashie::Rash id=31029929 name="GoncyRlz" profile_icon_id=7 revision_date=1375116256000 revision_date_str="07/29/2013 04:44 PM UTC" summoner_level=30>
```

I want to take that id and save it to a variable called `summonerid`. How can I take it?

Comment: [Here are some examples](https://github.com/Anujan/riot-api#usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just access the id as if it were a method on the object, i.e.

```
summonerid = summoner_details.id
```

Also see https://github.com/tcocca/rash